# Download Ubuntu Minimal ISO 20.04LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

Are there any plans to make the ISO available for this version?
On the [official](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A64-bit_PC_.28amd64.2C_x86_64.29_.28Recommended.29) page is not available...

Comment: The *official* page you mention was last updated some time ago (*2018-10-07 10:00:41* to remove 17.10 as EOL) being updated with the best information then available at the time.  Wiki's often only get updated when noticed..

Comment: So we do not have a minimal iso for 20/04 LTS, right?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It has moved to a new location: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso

Note that it moved to *legacy images*. Folks who use this image should start to look at newer options:

- [dd-able .img](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) images
- [Cloud images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/)
- [Ubuntu Base](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base)
- [Ubuntu Core](https://ubuntu.com/core)
- [Netboot-using-PXE](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510)

...and others.

Comment: Thanks for providing the legacy link. Do you happen to know which of the alternatives you linked most closely resembles the functionality / purpose of the mini.iso? I checked each of them, and it was not easy to tell as they all seem to have a different purpose in mind.

Comment: Depends upon if it's bare metal or a container/VM. If it's bare metal, depends upon the size and architecture. The closest equivalent I see for the functionality/purpose I care about (tiny download, includes kernel, deb based) is the Netboot-using-PXE, Folks who don't like PXE can use the 18.04/19.10 minimal and dist-upgrade it. Example: My next testing server build is likely to be Ubuntu Core on bare metal, with a bunch of LXD containers on top, each running a Cloud Image (or perhaps a Base Image).

Comment: Thanks for the extra context. Mostly, I care about the functionality you mentioned, tiny download, kernel, deb based, etc., but sometimes for bare metal, and sometimes on a vm / cloud. I should learn more about PXE and netbooting. :)

Comment: From what I can tell, none of the newer options offer < 100MB image/`.iso` file packages. Further: a lively discussion on this topic can be found here: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510

Comment: Seems Mini.iso is making a comeback in the upcoming Ubuntu 24.04! https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mini-iso/daily-live/current/