# How can I create a live usb bootable device (ie: Clonezilla) so files can be edited and saved

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

Hi I've looked all over for this answer and find very little if anything on the subject.  I'm trying to create an ubuntu customizable clonezilla bootable usb live device so I can update some files but can't seem to figure out how to do that.

If I create a live usb device from a clonezilla.iso file the entire live usb boot device is read only so I can't update files like syslinux.cfg, grub files, etc...  Is there a way to make that device (or even a single file) writeable after it's been created?

The other possibility I can think of is to unzip a clonezilla.zip file into a directory - change the necessary files to customize it - and then make a live bootable usb from that.  Is there documentation somewhere on how to do this and what settings that's needed to use?

Hope this all makes sense.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance, Blessings, Keith

Comment: What you're looking for is called **persistence**, but I don't think CloneZilla ISOs support persistence.  They're also heavily customized ISOs and not really Ubuntu as they're purpose-built tools rather than "use as a reusable editable system environment" ISO

Comment: Live USB vs Full install USB see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1367263/43926

Comment: ditch clonezilla and learn to do it the manually way: you mount the ISO as a squashfs and  you can then alter files on the ISO. Add and remove packages, change your system setup. change branding and anything else.

Comment: Mind that starting from a base system and working your way up ito a desktop s the default stance for Canonical. See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290075/xubuntu-20-04-minimal-installation/1293305#1293305 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1304682/15811