# How do I make ubuntu server as lightweight as possible. (Im trying to use the os for hosting something)

Tags: server, ram, cpu, hosting

incase your wondering, lightweight means taking the least amount of ram as possible. If anyone knows how to do this, please answer

Thanks in advanced (:

Comment: eh. You are mistaken: Ubuntu only has ONE server version and the notion of "light" does NOT apply to servers. The usage of RAM is determined by the services you use on your server. That is something you setup and is not part of a default server install.

Comment: There is a way, but you may be sacrificing a lot, and will maybe end up with almost same disk/RAM usage as if you just setup your server "normal way". The solution is to start with Ubuntu Base, then add the bare minimum for OS and your intended service to work. See this answer for more info: https://askubuntu.com/a/1293305/1080682 But keep in mind, you may be complicating your life for what.. 1GB RAM? So maybe it's worth it if you're running server on a 2GB machine :) If you have server with 64GB (or 512GB) RAM, difference will hardly be noticable. What do you plan to host?And on how much RAM?

Comment: To clarify, if your intended services have a lot of dependencies, you won't profit too much. If you need to add server, database, some framework, and their dependencies, modules and such, you'll be back to where you didn't want to be. But if you just put up a very lightweight service and that's it, and on weak hardware, then yes, try to play with Ubuntu Base. It's fun... And may lose you some hair along the way as well :)