# How do I get an ISO version of the latest version of Ubuntu minimal?

Tags: system-installation, iso

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233746/download-ubuntu-minimal-iso-20-04lts) question and clicked the link to the iso file and downloaded it. The ISO works it's just the version of Ubuntu it installs is old. Is there a way to get a ISO containing the latest version of Ubuntu minimal? I do not want a desktop enviorment.

Comment: The *minimal* ISO was never official supported; it was a by-product of a procedure used in creation of other *supported* ISOs, procedures that are no longer used, thus the ISO it appears to me you already have (ie. it doesn't exist for *modern* releases).  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD especially the "*Future of the MinimalCD*" section.

Comment: When installing 22.04 from the ISO, there is a "Minimal Option" on the Install / Updates and other Software page.

Comment: @guiverc seems mini.iso is making a comeback in the upcoming 24.04 tho: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mini-iso/daily-live/current/